# Ignoring "Enter" as newline in text widget in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a way when the user press "Enter" on the keyboard  not be considered as new line in Text widget in tkinter? I tried this but didn't work

```
num_of_workers= inputtxt2.get('1.0', 'end-1c').strip().replace("\n","")
```

Comment: do you want to disable Enter key?

Comment: Why not use ```Entry``` widget?

Comment: `just use an **KeyDown** function on related field !`

Comment: @dsgdfg can you give an example please?

Comment: yes , I want to disable it @Art

Comment: Then what is the need for a Text widget? You could use the Entry widget instead. Anyway if you still want to use Text you could bind `Return` and return `"break"`. (`text.bind("<Return>", lambda e: "break")`)